# how to test a value before a update in procedure plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a procedure What does an update of my clients with data from another table. And some customers are not updated by the failure of one of its values.

This is the error that throws : ORA - 12899 : value too large for column " TABLE_EXAMPLE " " BRANCH_CODE " (current : 3, maximum: 2).

And now this is the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE p_update_customers AS

CURSOR customer_data IS
  SELECT a.code_cust code_cust,
         '0' || a.branch_code branch_code,
         a.costumer_id,
         a.name name,
         b.description
    FROM customer a, description b
   WHERE a.costumer_id = b.costumer_id;

reg_customer_data customer_data%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
BEGIN
  OPEN customer_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH customer_data
      INTO reg_customer_data;
    EXIT WHEN customer_data%NOTFOUND;
    BEGIN
```

I think in this part i have to test branch code using IF or CASE Statements. I need only the two last digits of the value. (Between a BEGIN and UPDATE).

```
UPDATE table_example
         SET code_cust      = reg_customer_data.code_cust,
             branch_code    = reg_customer_data.branch_code,
             costumer_id    = reg_customer_data.costumer_id,
             name           = reg_customer_data.name,
             description    = reg_customer_data.description
       WHERE code_cust      = reg_customer_data.code_cust;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
END p_update_customers;
```

So, i need to test a branch_code before update, because i need only the two last digits (09 or 58).

```
costumer_id name      branch_code
  1         jose       09
  2         peter      09
  3         jhon       09
  4         charlie   058
```

If the branch_code has 3 digits, delete the first one and pass the 2 digits value and later continue with update.

Note: I cant change or delete the concat that i use in the cursor: CUSTOMER_DATA because the BRANCH_CODE on TABLE_EXAMPLE it must to be two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the cursor, you can still use a negative position value with [the `substr()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114) to count backwards from the end of a string, as Ed Gibbs showed, but against the cursor result set:

```
with t as (
  select 1 as costumer_id, 'jose' as name, '09' as branch_code from dual
  union all select 2, 'peter ', '09' from dual
  union all select 3, 'jhon', '09' from dual
  union all select 4, 'charlie', '058' from dual
)
select costumer_id, name, branch_code,
  substr(branch_code, -2) as new_branch_code
from t;

| COSTUMER_ID |    NAME | BRANCH_CODE | NEW_BRANCH_CODE |
|-------------|---------|-------------|-----------------|
|           1 |    jose |          09 |              09 |
|           2 |  peter  |          09 |              09 |
|           3 |    jhon |          09 |              09 |
|           4 | charlie |         058 |              58 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40406).

So you can change your update to set the value using the same call:

```
UPDATE table_example
         SET code_cust      = reg_customer_data.code_cust,
             branch_code    = substr(reg_customer_data.branch_code, -2),
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `'0' || a.branch_code branch_code` with one of the following based on the `customer.branch_code` data type...

- If it's numeric:

  ```
  TO_CHAR(a.branch_code, 'FM00') branch_code
  ```
- If it's varchar/varchar2:

  ```
  SUBSTR('0' || a.branch_code, -2, 2) branch_code
  ```

---

**Addendum**: OP noted that the cursor can't be changed, so the solution needs to be shifted to the update:

```
UPDATE table_example
     SET code_cust      = reg_customer_data.code_cust,
         branch_code    = SUBSTR(reg_customer_data.branch_code, -2, 2),
         costumer_id    = reg_customer_data.costumer_id,
         name           = reg_customer_data.name,
         description    = reg_customer_data.description
   WHERE code_cust      = reg_customer_data.code_cust;
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but a cant touch the CUSTOMER_DATA cursor.

Comment: @harsd - see the addendum to my answer, which alters the `UPDATE` and leaves the cursor alone; hope it works for you.